# Prevent duplications on polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphism, polymorphic-associations

I am setting up a polymorphic association on my application. I have a User table and an address table. Basically I want to achieve something like multiple users can share the same address.

My user model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_one :address, as: :addressable
end
```

My address model:

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
end
```

When I create a user and an address of that user, it worked fine. But what if my second user has the exact same address as the first user? I know it will work fine by creating another address with the `addressable_type` and `addressable_id` point to the second User.

`user1: #<User: id: 1>`, `user1.address` returns `address1`: `#<Address: id: 1, street: 'Fifth Avenue', city: 'New York', state: 'NY', addressable_type: 'User', addressable_id: 1`

How can I link my second User `user2: #<User: id: 2>` to `address1` without creating another address record that looks like: `#<Address: id: 2, street: 'Fifth Avenue', city: 'New York', state: 'NY', addressable_type: 'User', addressable_id: 2`

I plan to introduce more tables that potentially have same address with the `User` model.

Answer (score 0):

So there are several different problems you have:

### Normalize the address

You need to normalize your address otherwise different spellings will result in new records. Very simple approach could just be to e.g. store the downcased version of the street and city and remove any whitespace otherwise `Fifth Avenue` and `fifth avenue` are different records. However, this does not prevent you from different correct spellings like `5th Avenue` and `Fifth Avenue`. Maybe you can use a gem like [geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) to better normalize your address.

### Add validation to your address model

To make sure you don't store several times the same address, you might want to add a uniqueness validation to your address model.

```rb
validates :street, uniqueness: { scope: [:city, :state, :country] }
```

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness

### Use `find_or_create_by` when creating new address records

Now you can use `find_or_create_by` to avoid creating duplicate records in your controller (or wherever you would create the address).

```rb
Address.find_or_create_by(street: "5th Avenue", city: "New York", state: "NY")
Address.find_or_create_by(street: "5th Avenue", city: "New York", state: "NY")
# -> will only create one address object with these attributes
```

https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by

But as said, the hard problem will be to normalize your address first.

Comment: Hey Christian, thanks for your detailed answer. My question is more related to how to connect multiple user records to the same address record (e.g. user1, user2, all connect to address1) via polymorphic association.

Answer (score -1):

you need a join table, like so

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :user_address
  has_one :address, through: user_address
end

# user_addresses table has columns user_id and address_id
class UserAddress < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :address
end

class Address < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_addresses
  has_many :users, through: user_addresses
end
```

Comment: This does not answer the question how to not create duplicates.

Comment: It prevents duplicates addresses by associating (e.g) two users with the same address instead of creating two identical addresses for the two users. This is how I understood the OP question. Thanks for the down vote!